# Disable caching for Ace Editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ace-editor

I am writing a single page application that combines a tree directory and Ace editor for editing XML. The tree (done with JSTree) is created recursively from various file paths. When a valid node is clicked, an ajax call fetches the XML and sets the Ace Editor's value. The XML can then be edited and later POSTed to be saved.

My problem is that if a user presses CTRL+Z and there are no changes left in the current XML to undo, the value of the Ace Editor will be set to the previous file's value. At this point, the wrong node is now highlighted in the tree and the editor is displaying the "wrong" data.

Is it possible to disable caching in the Ace Editor or its DIV? I want to preserve the ability to CTRL+Z to undo changes in the current file, but want this to be cleared out/refreshed each time a new file is loaded into the editor.

Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

calling `editor.session.setValue` resets undomanager, but in this case it's better to use a new session instead

```
var oldSession = editor.session
var session = ace.createEditSession("text")
editor.setSession(session)
```

you can either keep old session to restore scroll position etc when opening same file, or call

```
oldSession.destroy()
```

to destroy it.